# Shapiro-Wilk test - are my data normal/non-normal?

Tags: goodness-of-fit, normality-assumption

Are my data normal/non-normal? How do you decide?

I performed a Shapiro Wilk test and got the following results. How do you interpret this?

```
swilk overall   nim opm roa roe

    Shapiro-Wilk W  test for normal data

Variable    Obs       W      V           z      Prob>z
overall    1236    0.96688   25.334     8.073   0.00000
    nim    1236    0.59705  308.265    14.314   0.00000
    opm    1236    0.81490  141.605    12.371   0.00000
    roa    1236    0.62534  286.622    14.132   0.00000
    roe    1236    0.70636  224.642    13.523   0.00000
```

Comment: Do you understand what a p-value is? Why are you testing normality?

Comment: of course I do understand what a p-value is. And the question that I have put forward was addressed to stochazesthai who responded to my initial question. Please allow him to respond. Thank you!

Comment: If you are referring to your question posted as an answer, the policy of not having questions in answer spaces is not mine; it's *how stackexchange works*. It will be removed whether I say anything about it or not. If you know what a p-value is, where does your difficulty lie? Again, *why are you testing normality*? It's important -- you should explain it in your question.

Comment: @David This is a forum open to all; there is no expectation that questions should be directed at one person and/or that answers should only be expected from one person. Somebody answering is not to be taken as your volunteer mentor until you have no more questions. Being polite about this makes no difference to the principle.

Answer (score 2):

Shapiro-Wilk is a statistical test used to assess whether your data are normally distributed. The null hypothesis is that your data are Normally distributed. If the p-value associated with the test statistics is lower than $\alpha$, where $\alpha$ is a statistical significance level, you can reject the null hypothesis and conclude that your data are **not** normally distributed. Conversely, when the p-value associated with the test statistics is greater than $\alpha$, you fail to reject the null hypothesis and conclude that your data are Normally distributed.

In your case, all the p-values are zero, and thus you can reject the null hypotheses and conclude that your data are **not** normally distributed.

Comment: This is correct, but the results the OP has do not imply that the non-normality is a problem for anything serious intended. It is just saying that the dataset is large enough to indicate that there is detectable non-normality in the variables using the criterion of a significance test. The larger question is how much non-normality and of what kind and what, if anything, should be done about it.